# Why is the derivative of i 0

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

I would like to know why the derivative of $i$ is 0. Someone explained that $i$ is a constant, but I thought $i$ was a complex number.

Also, is the derivative of, for instance, $5i$ = 0? Also, what would be the derivative of $2+3i$?

Thank you!

Comment: Whether the real or complex definition, the derivative of **any** number is zero.

Comment: The derivatiive of every constant function is zero. You are not taking a derivative of $i$ but the function which the image of any number is $i$, a constant function.

Comment: "*...but I thought that $i$ was a complex number*"  You know what else is a complex number?  $1$.  Yes, $1$ happens to be real too, but that doesn't prevent it from also being complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the derivatives of real and complex functions: 
$$f(x)=3 \Rightarrow f'(5)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(5+h)-f(5)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{3-3}{h}=0\\
f(x)=x \Rightarrow f'(5)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(5+h)-f(5)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(5+h)-5}{h}=1\\
--------------------------------------\\
f(z)=i \Rightarrow f'(5)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(5+h)-f(5)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{i-i}{h}=0\\
f(z)=z+2 \Rightarrow f'(5)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(5+h)-f(5)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(5+h+2)-(5+2)}{h}=1$$
Note:

1) $f(z)=i \Rightarrow f(2)=f(-3)=f(2+3i)=i$.

2) The derivative of a function shows   its rate of change and a constant function does not change, hence its derivative is zero.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of *any* complex constant is $0$. This follows from the definition of (complex) derivatives:
$$
f'(z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}.
$$

For instance, suppose $f(z)=3+5i$ for all $z$. Then the limit above would be $0$ for any $z_0$.

Answer (score 1):

$i$ is a constant like any other number

Now you say that it is a complex number .Yeah it's true but it is a constant number. When i change the value of $x$ value of $i$ remains the same. That's why it is a constant . $5i$ is a constant because whatever value i put in x the value of 5i remains the same. Like any other number i is also a number. What you are saying is like "why is 2 a constant, it is an integer"

Derivative of 2+3i in respect to x would be 0 because whatever value I input in x value of 2+3i will never change